# I want to add a location field in django model which take location input by putting lattitude and longitude

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-rest-framework

I also want to pick the location through Django REST API Through template..please suggest necessary django packages for it and how to write locationField in the Django Model

[this is the picture that django location field exactly which I want to Add please see it..](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L7gr0.gif)

Comment: https://pythonrepo.com/repo/caioariede-django-location-field--python-django-utilities

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create the multiple inputs field subclassing [`MultiValueField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/forms/fields/#multivaluefield):

```
class Location:
    def __init__(self, latitude, longitude):
        self.latitude = latitude
        self.longitude = longitude

class LocationField(MultiValueField):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        fields = (
            FloatField(max_value=90, min_value=-90),
            FloatField((max_value=90, min_value=-90)
        )
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)


    def compress(self, data_list):
        latitude, longitude = data_list
        return Location(latitude, longitude)
```

As for the second question, sorry, but it's very unclear what you are asking for.

Comment: store it as a point field https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/contrib/gis/geos/#django.contrib.gis.geos.Point

Answer (score 1):

I will try to be precise, I have build one similar project.
As you described in image in the link.
The following would do the job.
Make these changes in settings.py

```
'django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis',
```

Install this package https://pypi.org/project/django-map-widgets/
Add the below lines in Installed Apps:

```
    'django.contrib.gis',
    'mapwidgets'
```

Add these variables:

```
GOOGLE_MAP_API_KEY = "Create a google_map_api_key_and_past_it_here"

MAP_WIDGETS = {
    "GOOGLE_MAP_API_KEY": "Create a google_map_api_key_and_past_it_here"
}
```

In the models.py:

```
from django.contrib.gis.db import models
from django.contrib.gis.geos import Point

class Stack(models.Model):
    location = models.PointField(geography=True, spatial_index=True)
```

In forms.py:

```
from django.contrib.gis import forms as gis_forms
from django.contrib.gis.db import models as gis_models
from mapwidgets.widgets import GooglePointFieldWidget

class GoogleAddressForm(gis_forms.ModelForm):
    location = gis_forms.PointField(
        widget=widgets.GooglePointFieldWidget(
            ),
        )
    class Meta:
        model = Point
        fields = "__all__"
        formfield_overrides = {
            gis_models.PointField: {"widget": widgets.GooglePointFieldWidget()}
        }
```

In view simply render the template and pass the form in context.
In template using `{{form.location}}` would render the exact image with all those functionalities.